# Django/HTML: Send information through a button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

On my page, I have a modal that pops up asking for a purchase confirmation. This modal can be triggered by 10 different button presses corresponding to each item in my "shop". If possible, I would like to make it such that the price of the item, `{{ item.price }}` is visible within the modal window. How would I send this information alongside the button press? Would I have to define 10 different modals?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row centre-v">
  <div class="card shop-card">
    <div class="card-block shop-clock">
      <h3><span class="shop-tag">Shop</span></h3>
      {% if items %}
      {% for item in items %}
      <div class="alert alert-shop" role="alert">
        <span class="shop-title">{{ item.perk }}</span>
        <span class="shop-cost"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-shop" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#shopModal">Buy:&nbsp;{{ item.price }}<img class="coin-img shop-coin" src="{% static 'assets/coin.png' %}" height="20px" width="auto"></button></span>
        <div style="clear: right;"></div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="shopModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Purchase confirmation:</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This will cost you {{ item.price }}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it you already have all the information you need in the template and there is no need to reload the page or use AJAX.
I would override the onclick event in the button. The new function would receive all the information you want to show in the modal.

Lets say you have your button:

```
<button onclick="showMyModal({{ item.price }})">Buy</button>
```

Then you need to create the js function:

```
function showMyModal(itemPrice){
    /* populate the element with the price */
    document.getElementById("modal-price-element").innerHTML = itemPrice;
    /* Show the modal */

}
```

You may want to send more information through the function and add more data to the modal. You could also use JQuery if you are familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for making 10 different modals in an while loop but that is bad practice. The right solution is for making AJAX calls to the server by using JavaScript.

You need to make an JavaScript script that will do an AJAX call to the server with the id of the item. In Django you need to write an view that will give back the price (and other information) back by using JSON.

If you need to do a lot of this things I would recommend to look in the Django REST framework.

Answer (score 1):

As for me, the right solution will be to create one modal markup. And show on click the button loading info via AJAX call to the server.